# Authenticating API using options with got library

Tags: javascript, rest, npm

I am attempting to execute a basic API call that requires authorization using the `got` library. I attempted to use `options` to verify my username and password, but I get an `HTTPerror`.

Am I using options correctly?

```
const got = require('got');

(async () => {
       
      const options = {
              username: "myprojectID",
              password: "thesecret"
       }

    try {
        let raw_response = await got('https://altona.infura.io/beacon/block?epoch=1', options);
        let parsed_response = JSON.parse(raw_response.body);
        return parsed_response
    
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
   
    }
})()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using `options` incorrectly. Instead of `username` and `password` I used the following:

```
const options = {
        auth: "myprojectID:thesecret",
    }
```